# twitter widget only working in the first loading , then fails

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter

I have a web application which is developed using the Play Framework.
There I have used Ajax to load most of the view html pages to a div called 'container' .

```
$( "#container" ).load("/contactUs"); // contactUs is the page which contains the widget
```

I have this html page which includes the widget for my twitter feed.

```
<div id= "twitter_div">
                <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com//XXXX" data-widget-id="XXXXXX">Tweets by @@XXXX</a>
            </div>
```

When I click that page to load to the container it will load and the twitter feed will display correctly. 
then HTML would be

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-0" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" class="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered" allowfullscreen="" style="border: none; max-width: 100%; min-width: 180px; width: 331px;" title="Twitter Timeline" height="380"></iframe>
```

But after I load another html page to that same container div and then again if I load the twitter page to the same div it wont render properly.
ex :

first call `$( "#container" ).load("/contactUs"); // working properly`

then call `$( "#container" ).load("/home");`

and then again `$( "#container" ).load("/contactUs"); // not working properly`

It still shows

```
 <div id= "twitter_div">
                <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com//XXXX" data-widget-id="XXXXXX">Tweets by @@XXXX</a>
            </div>
```

Not the coverted `a` tag to an `Iframe`.

Why is this happening ?

**EDIT**

My contactUS page is like below

```
   <script> $(document).ready(function() { 
           !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)   [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");

   });
 </script>
   <div id= "twitter_div">
            <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com//XXXX" data-widget-id="XXXXXX">Tweets by @@XXXX</a>
   </div>
```

**EDIT 2**

I solved this issue using Mouser's solution

So now my main page is more like below.

```
<html>  
<head>
    <script>
        window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
            var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
            js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
            return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
            }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "container" ></div>
</body>
```

and my contactUS page is like,

```
 <script> $(document).ready(function() { 
      twttr.widgets.load();  
 });
 </script>
 <div id= "twitter_div">
        <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com//XXXX" data-widget-id="XXXXXX">Tweets by @@XXXX</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: also take a look intro  [this SO][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18490110/2654789

Comment: how that question is related to this question ?

Comment: Optimus @prime, Twitter plugins are loaded upon page initialization. After that you need to call the parser manually: `twttr.widgets.load()`;

Comment: @Mouser : I edited the question. So where should I insert the code part `twttr.widgets.load();`

Comment: actually I found that approach before in this SOQ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010188/twitter-widget-only-load-first-time-in-webapp-ajax-page

Comment: But the I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: twttr is not defined` in my browser console. browser is Chrome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using the following official Twitter loader:

```
    //TWITTER 
    window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
    var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
    js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
    }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

Look at the reference `window.twttr = (function (d,s,id)`. The code on your page is missing this.

My recommendation is to put this loader into your main page. Every time you load some external content into your div called `container` call the following code

```
twttr.widgets.load( $("#container")[0] );
```

Now Twitter should search that element for Twitter-elements and correctly parse them into timelines.